# VBA Trying to overwrite matching records and move non-matching records from ws1 to ws2

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement, do-while

It has been years since I've coded and I've tried many variations of looping. I've also spent many hours on StackOverflow, I am very greatful for the work you all put in.

I have 2 sheets, 1 workbook. Sheet1=DD and has thousands more records than sheet 2. DD has updated record info. All of the records from DD need to be moved to LC. However, there are many records that match from DD to LC, and the entire row from DD needs to replace the LC row. If the value in DD does not match an existing record in LC then the entire row needs to be moved to the end of LC.

Aug 1 update: I got the below to work, however, I need to break out of the loop when ohn is null. Right now it moves the record correctly but then keeps searching LC against a DD empty value.

```
Dim wsDD As Worksheet, wsLC As Worksheet 'shortens the names for each worksheet (ws) and records range (rng)
Dim rngDD As Range, rngLC As Range, colRng As Range
Dim lastRowDD As Long, lastRowLC As Long
Dim lastUIDused As Long 'holds the value of the last LC Unique ID when UniqueID col sorted by small-large
Dim ohnDD As Range, ohnLC As Range 'Old Host Number in DD or LC

Set wsDD = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataDump")
Set wsLC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LifeCycleAllRecs")
Set rngDD = wsDD.Range("A2", wsDD.Range("A" & wsDD.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)) 'finds & stores range of all used rows and columns in DataDump
Set rngLC = wsLC.Range("A2", wsLC.Range("A" & wsLC.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)) 'finds & stores range of all used rows and columns in LifeCycle

lastRowDD = wsDD.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row                              'stores last row # in DataDump
lastRowLC = wsLC.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row                              'stores last row # in LifeCycle tab

----------------- example 1-------------------
Set ohnDD = wsDD.Range("A2")
Set ohnLC = wsLC.Range("A2")
'for each cell in DD column, match with a cell in LC and return row number
'replace LC row with matching DD row
wsDD.Activate
    For Each ohnDD In wsDD.Range("Q1:Q" & lastRowDD)
        If ohnDD.Value > 0 Then 'ONLY IF NOT BLANK
            For Each ohnLC In wsLC.Range("X2:X" & lastRowLC)
                      MsgBox "2nd for ohndd " & ohnDD & "    ohnlc " & ohnLC
                      'And ohnDD.Value <> ""
                If ohnDD.Value = ohnLC.Value Then
                    wsDD.Range("A" & ohnDD.Row & ":U" & ohnDD.Row).Cut wsLC.Range("H" & ohnLC.Row)
                Else
                End If
            Next ohnLC
        Else
        End If
    Next ohnDD
```

This is has cost me days of getting nothing else done! I'm finally asking for help. I appreciate all help!

Comment: Incorrect: (LC which has updated record info). Correction: DD has updated record info, thus replacing LC recs with matching DD recs.

Comment: It would be better if you edited your question to correct rather than posting as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I added another IF statement just before If ohnDD.Value = ohnLC.Value Then
If ohnDD.Value <> "" Then

Seems to be working. A week of struggle finally come to an end!!